# Like and where condition in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the syntax for like in Ruby on Rails? This is something I'm trying to do:

I am trying to find all the last name from table which starts with egm so something `like %egm%`.  I know how to do using find_by_sql but just curious to know the Ruby way.

```
s = Person.find_by_last_name('nan%')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
l_name_var = "nan"
Person.where("people.last_name LIKE :l_name", {:l_name => "#{l_name_var}%"})
```

or in your case

```
l_name_var = "egm"
Person.where("people.last_name LIKE :l_name", {:l_name => "%#{l_name_var}%"})
```

Answer (score 19):

```
Person.where('name LIKE ?', '%egm%').all
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit, the `find_by_X` methods use the `=` operator, so you wouldn't want to use them for a like condition.  The "Rails" way involves using a bit of SQL inside of the where method as shown in the other answers.  The same would apply if you're trying to sort your results using the order method.